# Firebase Google Sign-In Not Showing Detailed Consent Screen on Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-studio, firebase-authentication

[image]

Hello everyone,

I'm currently working on integrating Google Sign-In into my Android application. As illustrated in the provided image (for context), my goal is to achieve a specific user flow, and I've managed to implement it successfully. However, I've encountered a challenge: when selecting an account, the system automatically proceeds to create the account without displaying the consent screen, regardless of whether the user is new or existing.

This behavior skips a crucial step in the user experience, where users should be informed about the data being shared and consent to it before account creation or sign-in. I'm seeking guidance on how to ensure that the consent screen is properly displayed to users as part of the Google Sign-In process.

Code:

```
fun signInWithGoogle(activity: Activity, requestCode: Int) {
    val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken(CLIENT_ID)
        .requestEmail()
        .build()

    val googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(activity, gso)
    val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
    activity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, requestCode)
}


private fun googleSignIn() {
    binding.googleSigninButton.setOnClickListener {
        EffectAnimation.bounceAnimation(it)
        val requestCode = GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE
        loginViewModel.signInWithGoogle(this, requestCode)

    }
}



override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE) { // The same request code you passed to signInWithGoogle
        val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
        try {
            val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)!!
            loginViewModel.firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.idToken!!)
        } catch (e: ApiException) {
           
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Not a full code. just an overview

[image]

I'm striving to achieve a specific flow with Google Sign-In in my Android app, developed in Kotlin. The process I envision is as follows:

Prompt the user to select a Google account.
For new users, display a consent screen detailing the information being shared (as depicted in the attached image).
Despite dedicating two days to this issue and thoroughly reviewing the documentation, I've yet to successfully implement this flow. My app is already linked to Google Cloud Platform and I've configured the OAuth consent screen, but something seems to be amiss.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or guidance from the community. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

P.S.: Apologies for any confusion; I'm determined to resolve this but have hit a stumbling block.

Comment: I'm not sure what in your code provides that behavior, but I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Comment: I am using old version. Can i achieve that in OneTap Login?  I tried to implement one tap login but not working too.

Comment: If you understand Java, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseAuthentication).

Answer (score 0):

Have you included SHA1 and SHA256 keys in your project?

If not, you need to add them from the Project Overview section on Firebase.

Firebase Overview -> Project Settings -> General -> Add Fingerprint

Comment: yes f course, I include that."